# Import class from other file (same namespace) in typescript + react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two files comment.tsx and commentlist.tsx

comment.tsx looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react-dom.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="interfaces.d.ts" />

import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

namespace W.T.F {
    export class Comment extends React.Component<ICommentData, {}>{
        constructor(props: ICommentData) {
            super(props);
        }

        public render() {
            return (
                <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentAuthor">{this.props.Author}</h2>
                <span>{this.props.Text}</span>
                    </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and commentlist.tsx

```
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react-dom.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="comment.tsx" />
/// <reference path="interfaces.d.ts" />

import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Comment = W.T.F.Comment;

namespace W.T.F {
    export class CommentList extends React.Component<ICommentListData, {}>{
        public render() {
            var commentNodes = this.props.Data.map(function (comment: ICommentData) {
                return (
                    <Comment Author={comment.Author} Text={comment.Text}>{comment.Text}</Comment>
                );
            });
            return (
                <div className="commentList">
                    {commentNodes}
                </div>
            );
        }
    };
}
```

compiling these files brings the error

commentlist.tsx(8,24) TS2305    Module 'W.T.F' has no exported member 'Comment'.

What is wrong in my source?

What is the best way to import other react classes (contained in namespaces) from other files?

Comment: Both of your files are “external modules” now. Move the import statements inside `namespace W.T.F`. You might need to change that to `declare namespace …` as well.

Comment: Checkout **Pitfalls** https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md. If you want to make this with namespaces working you must export them afaik.

Comment: hm.. i see i have to drop the namespaces in external modules, but what is the reason that .tsx files are handled as external modules and .ts files aren't?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript treats the file as an external module if there are any top level imports, and the namespace in your example becomes part of the module.

Most projects will want to use external modules without namespaces, but to use namespaces the way you're trying to, use the older reference/import syntax like this, with imports defined inside of the namespace:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/react/react.d.ts" />
namespace W.T.F {
    import React = __React;

    export class Comment extends React.Component<ICommentData, {}>{
        constructor(props: ICommentData) {
            super(props);
        }

        public render() {
            return (
                <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentAuthor">{this.props.Author}</h2>
                <span>{this.props.Text}</span>
                    </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited it to match your feedback

Comment: thanks for your answer. I removed the namespace in the current project. I will try your solution the next time to verify it.